# How to select multiple column from a data frame and within that i need to create two new column with existing column in the same code?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which consist of 5 columns. I need to extract the first 3 columns and I need to create two new columns from the last two columns?

column A
column B
column c
column D
column E

`df[df[1:3]]` this will give me first three column,
but from Column D & E I need to extract only the last two characters .
How can I extract in the same code ?

Comment: Please refer to this link on how to ask a question that will get you better responses & good answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to standardize your question which is at least reproducible  in order to get  a succinct answer and attention.

Answer (score 0):

Broadly I see that your dataframe has 5 columns. Say A B C D E. And in this DataFrame you want to add two new columns based on D and E. This is what your question is suggesting.

```
df[df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
x = df.D
y = df.E

df['F'] = x   # or just do df.F = df.D
df['G'] = y   # or df.G = df.E
```

You will have F and G new columns 'based on' (well technically equal-to) your last two columns D and E.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this should do the trick

```
df1= df.iloc[:,:3]
df2=df.iloc[:,3:]
a=df2.columns[:]
df2[a +'_extracted'] = df2[a].apply(lambda x: x.str[-2:])
```

**Input**

```
script  call_put    strike  animals     codes
a       280          280    rat     nill
a       260         260     cat     fill
a       275         275     pat     dill
b       280         280     mat     grill
b       285         285     bat     shrill
```

**Output**
df1

```
script  call_put    strike
0   a   280     280
1   a   260     260
2   a   275     275
3   b   280     280
4   b   285     285
```

df2

```
animals     codes   animals_extracted   codes_extracted
0   rat     nill    at  ll
1   cat     fill    at  ll
2   pat     dill    at  ll
3   mat     grill   at  ll
4   bat     shrill  at  ll
```